# query.getSingleResult() vs query.getResultList().get(0)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, collections

Given that my native SQL query returns a *single non-null* result, can somebody help me evaluate using **query.getSingleResult()** vs using **query.getResultList.get(0)**

Just for example:

```
String queryStr = "Select count(id) FROM Job J where companyMaster = 3";
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(queryStr);
return ((BigInteger) query.getResultList().get(0)).intValue();
```

produces the same result as:

```
String queryStr = "Select count(id) FROM Job Jo where companyMaster = 3";
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(queryStr);
return ((BigInteger) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using database method like getById then it is okay to use the getSingleResult method. In this case, you are sure that there is only one entity in the database matching that id.

But as you are performing a count, you should use the getSingleResult as it almost definitely will return you a result rather than using getResultList.get(0).